# How to "push" to new view controller after successful login StackMob

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, stackmob

I'm using stack mob as back-end provider and I'm trying to get my login screen to work.

After a successful login I want to move to a new `UIViewController`. It seems simple enough but I'm having issues.

I thought I could do this:

```
MyViewController* viewController = [[MyViewController alloc] init];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
```

Inside of the `onSuccess`:

```
- (IBAction)login:(id)sender {

[self.client loginWithUsername:self.usernameField.text 
             password:self.passwordField.text 
             onSuccess:^(NSDictionary *results) {

NSLog(@"Login Success %@",results);
```

Is there a better way to do this? Please help!

Comment: What's wrong with the code you posted?

Comment: Well it doesn't move from the initial view controller (the login screen) to the New one that its supposed to after successful login.

Comment: Why are you releasing viewcontroller?

Comment: well i've gotten rid of that release, but still no luck.

Comment: You really need to be more explicit about what's happening. Does anything happen when the above code runs? Do you know (by logging) whether the code actually does run. Do you have a navigation controller? Where is MyViewController created? In code? In a storyboard?

Comment: i have nslog printing that i have logged in successfully but no move to the new view controller. I do have a navigation controller on the storyboard with its own .h and .m files connected to it.the only place i have MyViewController created is where i posted above.

Answer (score 1):

What you posted is correct and it's the best way to do it.

If for some reason the view controller is not pushed correctly, it's probably because you are not pushing the new view controller on the right navigation controller stack.

Comment: Okay thank you. And im sorry im a bit of a noob, what do you meen by " you are not pushing the new view controller on the right navigation controller stack."?   what do i need to double check?         Do i need to make any connections on the storyboard? I believe i am able to do this all via code....

Comment: It all depends on how you set up the navigation controller and your storyboard. It's a very broad topic, so I suggest you read up on some view controller basics: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html